# How to trace DbQuery parameter values

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

We are tracing the generated SQL using qry.ToString.
How can we trace the parameter values too.

DbQuery (in contrast to ObjectQuery) does not have a Parameters property.

Using SqlProfiler is not an option. We are tracing using log4net in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a workaround using reflection see [Access to DbQuery parameters for logging](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/91c7fb6d-d1b8-4a7f-aec9-16336dbd619b/).
I made a [feature request at CodePlex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/619)